# ios universal app only show 3.5 inches screen instead of 4 inches screen

Tags: ios, screen, fullscreen, iphone-5, ios6.1

I have an app designed for universal devices.And I have all of the different dimensions of the launch images and app icons ready.

It was fine running on iphone 4, iphone 5  with iOS 7 devices and iphone 5 with ios 6.1

then, i found it was running not full screen (3.5 instead of 4 inches ) on the new ipod 5th generation with latest ios 7.

i update the project to use Images.xcassets then the problems solved.the app was running full screen.

However, it started only runs 3.5 inches (not full screen app) on iphone 5 with ios 6.1

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height
```

return 480 instead of 568

[image: image asset]

Any ideas ?

Comment: "It was fine running on [...] iphone 5 with ios 6.1 [...] I found the same issue occured on iphone 5 with ios 6.1" Can you please rephrase your issue?

Comment: @Beppe, does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

When using Xcode assets catalog, you need to be careful when setting up launch images. It is possible to have different launch images for iOS6 and iOS7. If you wish to use the same ones, make sure to link them correctly for each OS version.

[image]

Comment: i have double checked launch images for iphone portrait ios5,6 and rename them to a different files, however, my app on iphone 5 ios 6.1.4 still not getting the launch images. [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height still return 480 on iphone 5 instead of 568

Comment: @Kiddo When using the asset catalog, you shouldn't worry about naming. It's handled by Xcode. Perhaps post an image of how you have set up your images.

Comment: I had a similar issue: My app was running 'letterboxed'(black bars on top and bottom) on a 4 inch iPod Touch (5th generation), and the bounds reported 640x960 instead of 640x1136. This was in the iOS 6 era, so no asset catalogs. But i **was** including the file `Default-568h@2x.png` that **should** trigger 4 inch behaviour. Never found out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i found you have to have 2 different names for the retina 4-inch launch image (640x1136). how annoying.

[image: launch image]

Answer (score 0):

This issues was solved for me when I deleted the LaunchImage asset which contained 8 sets of images.

Which I then replaced with a new LaunchImage (using two finger click) containing only 3 image sets.